# How can I remove double lines detected along the edges?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator

I'm trying to take real time input for hand gestures with web cam, then processing the images to feed them to a neural network. I wrote this processing function to make the hand features look prominent:

```
    img = cv2.imread('hand.png')
   
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),2)

    th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,10,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)
    ret, res = cv2.threshold(th3, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
    res = cv2.Canny(res,100,200) 
    cv2.imshow("Canny", res)
```

The input and the output images are as follows:

[image]

[image]

It's obvious that double lines, instead of one, are detected along the edges (allover the hand, not only contour). I want to make them single. If I apply just Canny edge detection algo, then the edges are not very prominent.

Comment: Could you please share the original image? Also which lines exactly do you want to keep?

Comment: Why would you apply Canny after threshold? Canny is pointless to apply on a binary image, you can use a much cheaper algorithm to find the edges of your binary image (e.g. image minus erosion of the image). Canny is meant to be applied to a grayscale image, it is clever at distinguishing important edges from non-important ones.

Comment: @Prefect : I'm extremely sorry that I didn't share the input image last time. Now I added an input and its corresponding output in edit section of my Q.

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward solution would be `flood-fill` the background with `white` and then with `black` using `cv2.floodFill`, like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "hand.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Convert the image to Grayscale:
binaryImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Flood fill bakcground (white + black):
cv2.floodFill(binaryImage, mask=None, seedPoint=(int(0), int(0)), newVal=(255))

cv2.floodFill(binaryImage, mask=None, seedPoint=(int(0), int(0)), newVal=(0))

cv2,imshow("floodFilled", binaryImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result:

[image]

If you want to get a solid mask of the hand, you could try to fill the holes inside the hand's contour, also using `flood-fill` and some image arithmetic, like this:

```
# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "hand.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Convert the image to Grayscale:
binaryImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Isolate holes on input image:
holes = binaryImage.copy()
# Get rows and cols from input:
(rows, cols) = holes.shape[:2]

# Remove background via flood-fill on 4 outermost corners
cv2.floodFill(holes, mask=None, seedPoint=(int(0), int(0)), newVal=(255))
cv2.floodFill(holes, mask=None, seedPoint=(int(10), int(rows-10)), newVal=(255))
cv2.floodFill(holes, mask=None, seedPoint=(int(cols-10), int(10)), newVal=(255))
cv2.floodFill(holes, mask=None, seedPoint=(int(cols-10), int(rows-10)), newVal=(255))

# Get holes:
holes = 255 - holes
# Final image is original imput + isolated holes:
mask = binaryImage + holes

# Deep copy for further results:
maskCopy = mask.copy()
maskCopy = cv2.cvtColor(maskCopy, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

These are the isolated holes and hand mask:

[image]
[image]

You can then detect the `bounding rectangle` by processing `contours`, filtering small-area blobs and approximating to a rectangle, like this:

```
# Find the big contours/blobs on the processed image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get bounding rectangles:
for c in contours:

    # Filter contour by area:
    blobArea = cv2.contourArea(c)
    maxArea = 100

    if blobArea > maxArea:

        # Approximate the contour to a polygon:
        contoursPoly = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
        # Get the polygon's bounding rectangle:
        boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(contoursPoly)

        # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
        rectX = boundRect[0]
        rectY = boundRect[1]
        rectWidth = boundRect[2]
        rectHeight = boundRect[3]

        # Draw rectangle:
        color = (0, 255, 0)
        cv2.rectangle(maskCopy, (int(rectX), int(rectY)), (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 3)

        cv2.imshow("Bounding Rectangle", maskCopy)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm extremely sorry that I didn't share the input image last time. Now I added an input and its corresponding output in edit section of my Q. Could you plz see once?

Comment: Your solutions don't do well with the input image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on the correct way, but as @CrisLuengo mentioned, *Canny* is applied on grayscale images rather than binary images. Here is an approach.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2


img_gray = cv2.imread('hand.png',0)

sigma = 2
threshold1=30
threshold2=60

img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray,(5,5),sigmaX=sigma,sigmaY=sigma)
res = cv2.Canny(img_blur,threshold1=threshold1,threshold2=threshold2)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2,sharex=True,sharey=True)
ax[0].imshow(img_gray,cmap='gray')
ax[1].imshow(res,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

After playing around with the parameters of the gaussian filter and the Canny threshold values, this is what I am getting:

[image: fingers]

As you can see most of the fingers are clearly detected except the thumb. The lighting conditions make it difficult for *Canny* to calculate a proper gradient there. You might either try to improve the contrast of your images through your setup (which is the easiest solution to me), or to apply some contrast enhancements methods like [Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization (CLAHE)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html) before going for *Canny*. I did not get any better results than the one above after a few trials with CLAHE, though, but it might be worth to look at it. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. I'll see. In your solution the palm lines are not detected at all. Actually there will be 26 types of gestures for American Sign Language recognition. Multiple gestures look very similar just from the contours. So palm lines are also needed to be detected.

Comment: Your question is only about the double lines around the fingers. Could you please update your question according to your needs, e.g., input and expected output?

Comment: By edges I meant, allover - NOT only contours (outer edge). May be, I didn't express properly. Anyway, made an edit in my original Q.